# "refusing to allow a GitHub App to create or update workflow" when not modifying a workflow file

Tags: git, github

When running

```
git push origin releases/1.13.7 --porcelain --quiet
```

in a GitHub action, I get

```
!   refs/tags/releases/1.13.7:refs/tags/releases/1.13.7 [remote rejected] (refusing to allow a GitHub App to create or update workflow `.github/workflows/release.yml` without `workflows` permission)
```

This error message doesn't make any sense, as (a) I haven't modified that file during the workflow and (b) I'm pushing a tag pointing at an existing commit.

Comment: The error message is poor, yes, but the complaint is clear: they won't let anything create a *name* (maybe just a tag name, though I'd expect the same error for a branch name too) that refers to anything *containing* such a file unless the creator has the given permission. That is probably done to avoid some particular security hole that would be produced by allowing it.